# Delete Cookies on Page start up

Tags: javascript, jsp, cookies, widget, liferay

I'm trying to delete a cookie on start up of a Liferay Server webpage. The page is completely static and its content is build up with wigdets. I'm new to this stuff, so I received a hint to create a new wigded, which is loaded on that page and its only function is to delete some specific cookies.

So i put a new wigded on this page, made him load some jsp file, and this file contains following code:

```
<%
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
if (cookies != null)
{
    for (Cookie cookie:cookies)
    {
        if(cookie.getName().equals("Cookie1")  || cookie.getName().equals("Cookie2"))
        {
            Cookie clearCookie = new Cookie(cookie.getName(), null);
            clearCookie.setMaxAge(0);
            clearCookie.setPath("/");
            response.addCookie(clearCookie);
        }
    }
}
%>
```

So far this one works partially. It receives all Cookies from the request Object, it also finds both cookies I'm looking for, but when it comes to that part where the cookies has to be replaced, there is no change. Even if i try to create new cookies, it doesn't work I suppose it has to do with the response object, because I probably have to deliver it to something. But how can I achieve this?

I also tried it with Javascript like this:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
      document.cookie = "Cookie1=;Path=/";
      document.cookie = "Cookie2=;Path=/";
    };
</script>
```

Here is the problem, that the cookies I wanted to replace, weren't replaced. Instead this script just created a second batch of cookies with the same Name and Path like the first one but with an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we managed to control cookies. You can create hook which extends Action class. Here are parts of code, you can use.

```
public class ManageCookiesAction extends Action {

    @Override
    public void run(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ActionException {

    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

    /** Manage cookies in you scenario... **/

    }
}
```

then in ../resource/portal.properties

```
servlet.service.events.pre=net.your.hook.class.package.ManageCookiesAction
```

We were using it to manage redirection to site saved in cookies of each user (they could have their own home sites on our portal) Might be useful in your scenario as well. Good luck.